# Sending 500 ("Server Error") response when visiting any url in Sails App

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js

I am using Sails and Mysql to handle the database of my app. I recently clicked on a chrome autofill URL that took me to a 404'd page, since that url `localhost:1337/companies` was not active in this project.

Ever since I did that, my app returns

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'
```

and

```
Details:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'
```

any time I go to a url in my app. I tried cloning my app and relinking the database to no avail. I see this is a common issue people run into with sails, but none of the mentioned solutions were able to fix it for me.

Everything was working before I clicked that URL which makes me believe it may be a route issue, but the app still works, it will just fill up my terminal with the above errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: this is the custom API call I was working on in my controller.js when I started seeing the error:

```
winner: function (req, res) {

  User.findOne({id: req.param('id')}).exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
          return res.negotiate(err);
      }
      else {
          var u = user;
          u.totalwins++;
          u.save();
          sails.io.sockets.emit("chat", {verb:"score", data:{id: req.param('id'), name: user.name}});
      }
  });

}
```

Also receiving this error in my chrome-browser console:

> :1337/user/quizzes Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you're on a test/non-production database, have you tried truncating the table?

Comment: your application is running a query, which apparently takes the column name as a parameter from javascript and the column name is passed as NAN, which is invalid. If you fix that issue, your 500 error might go away.

Comment: Just ran truncate on the table, but still receiving the 500 error.

Comment: @Sparrow, I reverted back to a clean form that didn't have the error, and it started doing it again.

Comment: @Sparrow I updated question showing my custom api query that may or maynot be causing this

Comment: How does quizzes get called? You need to trace your code. The errors that you are posting, are happening in the server side code and I am guessing that you are not passing the parameters to the server side code properly.

Comment: I notice your custom api call doesn't check for no result for `User.findOne`. The query may run without error, but if no matching user is found, the `user` argument in the callback is `false`. Just a thought.

Comment: try starting sails like this LOG_QUERIES=true sails lift, it will log your queries and then you can check which of you query is creating problem

Comment: @Arshad Thanks for that, it helped me debug that my app was looking at my incremented id column and trying to find records `where id = null` which isn't possible. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835962/sails-js-mysql-unknown-column-nan-in-where-clause) provided me with a solution.